# how to test if properties is from another assembly

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection, internal, func

i am trying to test this method:

```
[Test]
public void Test_GetReferenceValue()
{
  Person person= new Person() { Name = "PJ" };
  PersonalProperty<Person> personalProperty = new PersonalProperty<Person>();
  var result = personalProperty.GetReferenceValue(person);
  Assert.AreEqual("PJ", result);
}
```

the method GetReferenceValue has the following implementation:

```
public override object GetReferenceValue(TOwner owner)
{
    Person value = this.Accessor(owner);

    if (value == null)
        return null;
    else
        return value.Name;
}
```

i tried to find the origin of the Accessor property, and i found it in ANOTHER assembly:

```
public class PersonalProperty<TOwner> : Property<TOwner, Person>
where TOwner : class
{
  public virtual Func<TOwner, TProperty> Accessor { get; internal set; }
}
```

my test above will run perfectly if only i can put the code in my test:

```
   personalProperty.Accessor = p =>p;
```

this is to put a definition/method for the Func delegate.. however, i cant do this because Accessor is internally set. Meaning, i cant set it if i am in an another assembly (which i am right now). i cant friend the Accessor's assembly because i am not allowed to change any code. i am only allowed to create a test in an another project/assembly.

so how am i going to test GetReferenceValue? can reflection help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using reflection. This function can set property value ignoring setter access modifier:

```
public static void SetPropertyValue(object instance, string property, object value)
{
    instance.GetType().GetProperty(property).SetValue(instance, value, null);
}
```

Usage:

```
Func<Person, Person> accessor = p => p;
SetPropertyValue(personalProperty, "Accessor", accessor);
```

Anyway, it is an indicator that something might be wrong with `PersonalProperty<T>` class design.

Comment: OMG... actually i tried this earlier but not successful coz im doint it the wrong way: .SetValue(personalProperty, p=>p, null);
lol... so lambda is not allowed there and i didnt know until now that x in Func<Person, Person> x = p => p; is actually an object... THanks for this!